# IBM Worklight - "Unfortunately, HelloWorkLight has stopped" error message

Tags: android, adt, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a simple HelloWorld application with the Android environment. When I run it in my android device (ICS version) i get this error message:

> Unfortunately, HelloWorkLight has stopped

When I run it in the Android emulator (version 2.2), I get this error:

> Sorry! The application HelloWorkLight (process com.HelloWorkLight) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. Force Close.

I have no idea what to do with this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using ADT v22.
To resolve this issue:

1. Right-click on the native Android project in Worklight Studio
   and choose 'Properties'.
2. Select 'Java Build Path' and go to the 'Order and Export'
   tab.
3. Mark the check-box for 'Android Private Libraries'
4. Refresh/clean/rebuild the android project.

You will need to do the above per-project.
This is fixed internally for a future Worklight release.

Comment: thanks alot Mr. Idan, i have been do that. and then i try to create new project, i got same error although i have been check list for "android Private Libraries, and then i try to uncheck list that option, and then check list again. and it work. it little bit confuse me.