# Error when run Worklight app in android device

Tags: android, exception, ibm-mobilefirst

I try to develop an app with IBM worklight, when i try to run it in Worklight console, it run normal. but when I try to run it on my android app I got error. In my device show this message

```
Unfortunately app name stopped
```

and in logcat i got this message

```
06-26 17:16:55.749: E/AndroidRuntime(5105): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 17:16:55.749: E/AndroidRuntime(5105): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.Myapp/com.Myapp.Myapp}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Myapp.Myapp"
```

i have check list on android private library. what should i do? anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably installed ADT v22.
This happens due to a change Google has made in this version of ADT.
It affects users of ADT v22 only.

Follow these instructions (on a per-project basis):

1. Right-click on your generated Android project and choose
   "properties"
2. From the left pane, choose "Java Build Path'
3. Tick the "Android Private Libraries" checkbox
4. Refresh the project / re-build the app

The app should now successfully launch in the device.

Make sure to do Project >> Clean... in case the above didn't help (that's essentially step 4).

Comment: What changed since what you've done here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129623/ibm-worklight-unfortunately-helloworklight-has-stopped-error-message/17130121#17130121

What did you do in your project?

Comment: yeah.. that work.. clean my project.. 
i didn't do anything except change code in main html (worklight).. thank you very much one again Mr Idan..