# IBM Worklight 5.x - Worklight app in Android closes with "Unfortunately the app has stopped"

Tags: android, adt, ibm-mobilefirst

My application runs perfectly when previewed in the Worklight Console, but whenever I launch it in an Android device, it fails and closes with this error message:

> `Unfortunately <appName> has stopped`

The error message in LogCat:

> Fatal Exception:main
>
> java.lang.Runtime Exception unable to instantiate the activity
>   component
>
> class not found exception

Comment: Please post full error given by your Eclipse Logcat errorlog

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ADT v22?

See if this helps you: [IBM Worklight - "Unfortunately, HelloWorkLight has stopped" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129623/ibm-worklight-unfortunately-helloworklight-has-stopped-error-message)

1. Right-click on the native Android project in Worklight Studio
   and choose 'Properties'.
2. Select 'Java Build Path' and go to the 'Order and Export'
   tab.
3. Mark the check-box for 'Android Private Libraries'
4. Refresh/clean/rebuild the android project.

You will need to do the above per-project.
This is fixed in the now publically availble Worklight 6.0.