# IBM Worklight 5.x - Android app stops and terminates unexpectedly

Tags: android, adt, ibm-mobilefirst

I have tried to develop a test application using Worklight for the Android environment. When I run the app using an AVD it throws an error message like:

> "Sorry The application Test (process com.AccorFintech) has stopped
>   unexpectedly. Please try again."

and the application terminates.
I am using Eclipse 4.2 and android version for AVD is Android 2.2.

Here Is My Logcat:

```
07-01 16:19:33.510: W/dalvikvm(403): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/AccordFintech/AccordFintech; (12)
07-01 16:19:33.510: W/dalvikvm(403): Link of class 'Lcom/AccordFintech/AccordFintech;' failed
07-01 16:19:33.540: D/AndroidRuntime(403): Shutting down VM
07-01 16:19:33.540: W/dalvikvm(403): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.AccordFintech/com.AccordFintech.AccordFintech}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.AccordFintech.AccordFintech in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.AccordFintech-2.apk]
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.AccordFintech.AccordFintech in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.AccordFintech-2.apk]
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
07-01 16:19:33.570: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using ADT v22?

See if this helps you: [IBM Worklight - "Unfortunately, HelloWorkLight has stopped" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129623/ibm-worklight-unfortunately-helloworklight-has-stopped-error-message)

1. Right-click on the native Android project in Worklight Studio
   and choose 'Properties'.
2. Select 'Java Build Path' and go to the 'Order and Export'
   tab.
3. Mark the check-box for 'Android Private Libraries'
4. Refresh/clean/rebuild the android project.

You will need to do the above per-project.
This is fixed in Worklight 6.0.

Comment: This is now fixed in Worklight 6.0. Available publically now.

Comment: Will you please elaborate your first step ?

Comment: After you build your app, an Android project is generated, as you can see in the project explorer view in Eclipse. Right-click it and choose "Properties".